# How to have a char pointer as an out parameter for C++ function

Tags: c++

I'm a newbie to C++. I'm trying to have a char pointer as an out parameter for a function. But the changes made in the function are not reflected in the main function. What am I doing wrong?

```
void SetName( char *pszStr )
{
    char* pTemp = new char[10];
    strcpy(pTemp,"Mark");
    pszStr = pTemp;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    char* pszName = NULL;
    SetName( pszName );
    cout<<"Name - "<<*pszName<<endl;
    delete pszName;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Your pointer is being copied onto the stack, and you're assigning the stack pointer. You need to pass a pointer-to-pointer if you want to change the pointer:

```
void SetName( char **pszStr )
{
    char* pTemp = new char[10];
    strcpy(pTemp,"Mark");
    *pszStr = pTemp; // assign the address of the pointer to this char pointer
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    char* pszName = NULL;
    SetName( &pszName ); // pass the address of this pointer so it can change
    cout<<"Name - "<<*pszName<<endl;
    delete pszName;
    return 0;
}
```

That will solve your problem.

---

However, there are other problems here. Firstly, you are dereferencing your pointer before you print. This is incorrect, your pointer is a pointer to an array of characters, so you want to print out the entire array:

```
cout<<"Name - "<<pszName<<endl;
```

What you have now will just print the first character. [Also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217173/how-to-have-a-char-pointer-as-an-out-parameter-for-c-function/1217219#1217219), you need to use `delete []` to delete an array:

```
delete [] pszName;
```

---

Bigger problems, though, are in your design.

That code is C, not C++, and even then it's not standard. Firstly, the function you're looking for is `main`:

```
int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
```

Secondly, you should use [references](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/references) instead of pointers:

```
void SetName(char *& pszStr )
{
    char* pTemp = new char[10];
    strcpy(pTemp,"Mark");
    pszStr = pTemp; // this works because pxzStr *is* the pointer in main
}

int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    char* pszName = NULL;
    SetName( pszName ); // pass the pointer into the function, using a reference
    cout<<"Name - "<<pszName<<endl;
    delete pszName;
    return 0;
}
```

Aside from that, it's usually better to just return things if you can:

```
char *SetName(void)
{
    char* pTemp = new char[10];
    strcpy(pTemp,"Mark");
    return pTemp;
}

int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    char* pszName = NULL;
    pszName = SetName(); // assign the pointer
    cout<<"Name - "<<pszName<<endl;
    delete pszName;
    return 0;
}
```

There is something that makes this all better. C++ has a [string class](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string):

```
std::string SetName(void)
{
    return "Mark";
}

int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    std::string name;

    name = SetName(); // assign the pointer

    cout<<"Name - "<< name<<endl;

    // no need to manually delete
    return 0;
}
```

If course this can all be simplified, if you want:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string get_name(void)
{
    return "Mark";
}

int main(void)
{
    std::cout << "Name - " << get_name() << std::endl;        
}
```

You should work on your formatting to make things more readable. Spaces inbetween your operators helps:

```
cout<<"Name - "<<pszName<<endl;

cout << "Name - " << pszName << endl;
```

Just like spaces in between English words helps, sodoesspacesbetweenyouroperators. :)

Comment: +1, answers direct problem, and illuminates the bigger issue with the code.

Comment: There is no need to declare a void parameter, and main should have parameters of type int and char**.

Comment: There's no need but it's what I prefer. And that declaration of main is completely valid.

Comment: delete should also have [] after it and before the string name other wise it will only delete the first element

Comment: This may be too late, but `strcpy()` is a bad idea. He should be using `strncpy()` instead which is a measure against buffer overflow.

Answer (score 8):

You can also use a reference to a pointer int this case. Also, you may want to be aware of 2 other bugs which are in the original code (see my comments in the code snippet).

```
 void SetName( char *& pszStr )
 {
     char* pTemp = new char[10];
     strcpy(pTemp,"Mark");
     pszStr = pTemp;
 }

 int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
 {
     char* pszName = NULL;
     SetName(pszName);

     // Don't need '*' in front of pszName.
     cout<< "Name - " << pszName << endl;

     // Needs '[]' to delete an array.
     delete[] pszName;
     return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Nice catch on the array delete.

Answer (score 4):

Since you tagged as C++, why not pass in a std::string reference and fill it?

```
void GetName(std::string &strName)
{
    strName = "Mark";
}
```

Or simply return an std::string:

```
std::string GetName2()
{
  return "Mark";
}
```

And call it like so

```
std::string strName, strName2;
GetName(strName);
strName2 = GetName2();
assert(strName == "Mark");
assert(strName2 == "Mark");
//strName.c_str() returns the const char * pointer.
```

Then you don't have to worry about freeing any memory.

Comment: And don't forget to #include <string>
:)

Answer (score 2):

What you are writing is not C++, but C code that uses new instead of malloc, and delete instead of free. If you really want to write C++ code, start again. Read a book like [Accelerated C++](http://www.acceleratedcpp.com/), which will teach you modern idiomatic C++.

Comment: The last line of the question was "What am I doing wrong?" I think my answer addresses this exactly.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll definitely go through the book.