# Where to free up memory of a dynamic array created inside a function

Tags: c++, local-variables, delete-operator

This is in reference to the discussion in this topic here
[How to have a char pointer as an out parameter for C++ function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217173/how-to-have-a-char-pointer-as-an-out-parameter-for-c-function)

In the code below, where do I free the memory of **pTemp**? Is it not required?
Would things would have changed in anyway if instead of array of chars there was array of integers?

```
void SetName( char **pszStr )
{
    char* pTemp = new char[10];
    strcpy(pTemp,"Mark");
    *pszStr = pTemp;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char* pszName = NULL;
    SetName( &pszName );
    cout<<"Name - "<< pszName << endl;
    delete [] pszName;
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pTemp`, the variable *itself*, is deallocated once the function exits since it was allocated on the stack in the first place. The array whose pointer was put into `pTemp` persists outside the function via the argument passed to it, `pszName`. When the value in *this* variable is deleted, the heap memory used by the array will be freed.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Totally missed out the point that variable pTemp was in stack.

Answer (score 7):

You're assigning `pTemp` to `*pszStr`, and `pszStr` points to `pszName`.

Therefore, `delete [] pzxName` deletes the allocated memory as required.

The confusion is a good example of why you should avoid weird C-style idioms and manual memory management. It would be much clearer as:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

std::string GetName() {return "Mark";}

int main() {
    std::string name = GetName();
    std::cout << "Name - " << name << std::endl;
}
```

with no pointers, `new` or `delete` required.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to.
The memory allocated to it is deallocated when you call:

```
delete [] pszName;
```

Note, that `new`/`new []` returns you a address and to avoid a memory leak you need to call `delete`/`delete []` on the **exact same address** and **only once**.

What you have in above code is two different pointers(`pszName` and `pTemp`) pointing to the same address which was returned by `new []`. So calling `delete []` on one suffices.

In C++ you are much better off using a `std::string` instead of `char *` and in case of other data types, You surely can use **smart pointers** and save yourself the explicit memory management.