# Making Char pointer an out parameter in C

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to write a function that reverses a string. The basic algorithm works but I'm failing to affect the input parameter that is being passed when called, inside the unit test. I do not believe this is a duplicate as I am running into new problems.

strings_test.c

```
char *test_reverse_string()
{
    char rv1[512];  // these are not changing below but should
    char rv2[512];  // (yet the first test is passing just length is failing)
    char str1[] = "hello world";
    char str2[] = "a man a plan a canal panama";

    mu_assert(check_strings(reverse_string(rv1, str1), "dlrow olleh") == 0, "Your reverse_string function did not correctly reverse a string.");
    reverse_string(rv1, str1);
    printf(":::::%s:::::;;;;;%i;;;;;", rv1, strlen(rv1)); // I added this line for debugging. It alerted me to fact it wasn't being copied

// This next is the first test that fails 
        mu_assert(strlen(rv1) == 11, "Your reversed string does not have the same length as the original string.");
        mu_assert(check_strings(reverse_string(rv2, str2), "amanap lanac a nalp a nam a") == 0, "Your reverse_string function did not correctly reverse a string.");
        mu_assert(strlen(rv2) == 27, "Your reversed string does not have the same length as the original string.");
    
        return NULL;
    }
```

From running printf(), I notice rv1 and rv2 stay empty. I believe that this is because a copy is being made on the stack when the function is called and I have to make a pointer to a pointer, which I have tried, but which gives me errors. I have been trying to implement this advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217173/how-to-have-a-char-pointer-as-an-out-parameter-for-c-function).

The function definitions were given to us as is, but I modified them accordingly (with the extra asterix). I don't know what approach they are expecting students to take. My approach is probably different and more complex but I believe it should work fine. BTW it's an archived course for a module of a coding camp and I've also graduated and I want to stick with my line of attack if possible, therefore I'm here not there.

My Code:

strings.h

```
#ifndef strings_h
#define strings_h

int string_length(char s[]);

char *reverse_string(char rv[], char s[]);

#endif
```

strings.c

```
char *reverse_string(char **rv, char *s) // Note this definition was given, but with only one '*' next to rv. I added second
{
    int length = string_length(s);
    int temp;
    *rv = s;  // I likewise added all the *'s here and below

    for (int g = 0; g < length / 2; g++)
    {
        temp = *rv[length - g - 1];
        *rv[length - g - 1] = *rv[g];
        *rv[g] = temp;
        // s[length] = "\0";
    }
    return s; // have to return this. Returning rv is wrong type. Return doesn't matter
}
```

After trying the suggestion on the other [S/O post linked above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217173/how-to-have-a-char-pointer-as-an-out-parameter-for-c-function) I thought it would begin to work. Instead, of course since the definition in the h file was different, I knew I had to change that because I got this error:

```
strings.c:29:7: error: conflicting types for ‘reverse_string’    29 | char *reverse_string(char **rv, char *s)
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~ In file included from /usr/include/string.h:431,
                 from strings.c:3: ./strings.h:6:7: note: previous declaration of ‘reverse_string’ was here
    6 | char *reverse_string(char rv, char s[]);
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~ make: *** [<builtin>: strings.o] Error 1
```

When I change the .h file to the following:

```
char *reverse_string(char **rv, char s[]);
```

I get a Segmentation fault (core dump) error, which I read up on, and this is where I'm stuck.

PS I tried using a reference instead, as suggested

```
char *reverse_string(char *&rv, char *s)
```

but I get

```
error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘&’ token
```

EDIT: I found another guy in the program whose test passed. I don't know why his works and mine didn't. Mine works when I run Make and then ./strings, but not when I run "make tests". In other words I get what's expected when I'm debugging, but when I actually run it in tests it fails. I am new to make and this way of testing and that confused me. I still don't know fully what's going on. I see one source of confusion is in the output log, which gives some misleading data.

This is the full output of the other guy's function that works and passes.

```
tests/strings_tests.c:26:31: warning: format ‘%i’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘size_t’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’} [-Wformat=]
   26 |     printf(":::::%s:::::;;;;;%i;;;;;", rv1, strlen(rv1));
      |                              ~^             ~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                               |             |
      |                               int           size_t {aka long unsigned int}
      |                              %li
In file included from tests/strings_tests.c:2:
tests/strings_tests.c: In function ‘main’:
tests/../../utils/minunit.h:17:38: warning: parameter ‘argc’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-parameter]
   17 | #define RUN_TESTS(name) int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {\
      |                                  ~~~~^~~~
tests/strings_tests.c:44:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘RUN_TESTS’
   44 | RUN_TESTS(all_tests);
      | ^~~~~~~~~
sh ./tests/runtests.sh
Running unit tests:
-----
RUNNING: ./tests/strings_tests
:::::dlrow olleh:::::;;;;;11;;;;;ALL TESTS PASSED
Tests run: 2
tests/strings_tests PASS
```

Notice the first printf line (line three). I added this. That throws an error, but that same line is below and the tests pass. I inserted the printf line into the test file to debug because it aborts when the test fails and I wanted to see if something came up. When I ran my code it therefore aborted. I see he too had the same empty line ::::::;;;;- so in other words because I didn't know how to read this, I got a false negative, or was led down the wrong track. Well, that and the other post here[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217173/how-to-have-a-char-pointer-as-an-out-parameter-for-c-function) that talked about how you have to have a pointer to a pointer for an outparameter, so it made perfect sense, but doesn't anymore.

As to why my algorithm failed, I am not sure because it works in my make file when I run main. The only difference I see is he terminated the string with '/0' whihc they said to do, but I thought that changing it in place would preserve that character. When I try to add it manually, I keep getting errors. I am so confused why it hates my way of doing things

```
// Tests pass on this copied algorithm
char *reverse_string(char *rv, char *s)
{

    int rslength = string_length(s);
    int index = 0;

    for (int i = rslength - 1; i >=0; i--) {
      rv[index] = s[i];
      index = index + 1;
    }
    rv[index] = '\0';
    return rv;

}

//tests fail. properly reverses string but doesn't get right length
char *reverse_string(char *rv, char *s) 
{
    int length = string_length(s);
    int temp;
    (rv) = s;
    int g;

    for (g = 0; g < (length / 2); g++)
    {
        temp = (rv)[length - g - 1];
        (rv)[length - g - 1] = (rv)[g];
        (rv)[g] = temp;

    }
    // rv[length] = '\0';  // Whether I add this line or not I get the error below 
    return rv;
}
```

Error

[ERROR] (tests/strings_tests.c:27: errno: None) Your reversed string does not have the same length as the original string.
make: *** [../mainbuild.mk:47: tests2] Error 1

Comment: `// I added second` Why? The output buffer `rv` is received as an argument, you don't need to (and in this case you cannot) change it..

Comment: All of your `*rv[i]` reverences are missing needed parentheses.  Change them all to `(*rv)[i]`.  But why do you have both `rv` and `s`?  It makes no sense since the string is reversed in-place.

Comment: Plus you're passing a `char *` for `rv` when it requires a `char **`.  The only way you can use it as currently declared is by passing the address of a pointer variable.  But as mentioned, you need to just remove the `rv` parameter, since it serves no purpose.

Comment: I have the rv parameter since we were given the function definitions, that accord to the unit test and the header files. I didn't want to alter the parameters except to access the original pointer. The unit test doesn't accept a return value. It wants it's input argument altered. That's why I thought I needed an * or maybe a & but basically I left things as they were given.

Comment: I made some edits with some more info above. I think I was on the wrong track based on some false or misread clues. I still don't understand why I get the length error. The output when debugging is right.